# Passing HTML code as string variable to template for PDF generation

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, pdf-generation

I'm working on a Django app which parses xlsx input, processes series of REST API queries and returns the result of the queries as a table in one of my django templates. The HTML code containing the results table is generated with Pandas.to_html() functionality. The HTML code is stored in a variable ("table") and passed to the html template, where it is displayed as {{ table | safe }}. This mechanism works just fine. However, I'm now struggling to add a button which would generate a pdf file to be downloaded by the user.

NOTE: I'm aware it would probably make more sense to use JS to render the PDF on the client side, but at the moment the point is to avoid doing so.

Upon some research, I decided to go with the [django-easy-pdf library](https://django-easy-pdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html). I based my solution on the example included in the documentation, but so far to no avail.

**In urls.py:**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    [...]
    path('result.pdf', views.PDFView.as_view(), name='PDFview'),
]
```

**In views.py:**

```py
class PDFView(PDFTemplateView):
        template_name = 'whitelist/listresult.html'
        table = None
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
                return super(PDFView, self).get_context_data(pagesize='A4', title='Hi there!', table=self.table, date=date.today)
```

Please note that the template "listresult.html" is the one expecting the {{ table }} variable.

Last but not least, in the very **listresult.html** (where I want to place the button to render the PDF file), I added a simple button object:

```html
<a class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg" href="{% url 'PDFview' table %}">Download PDF</a>
```

My expectation was that since I'm sending the "table" variable along with the request for PDF url, the view would process it nicely and prompt the user with a download pop-up for the PDF file looking exactly (or almost exactly) as the page which presented the result in the first place. However, I'm cought in a vicious circle where if I add "table" to the url reference on the site I get an error during template rendering for the very website displaying results (NoReverseMatch for ..., Reverse for 'PDFview' with arguments '['table' contents go here] not found). On the other hand, if I remove the "table" argument from the url reference, the results website renders OK with the "Download PDF" button, but upon clicking it I'm left with a Runtime Error (since context is missing).

I'm 97% confident my mistake is ostentatiously stupid, but after x hours of struggle I'm ready for StackOverflow's judgement.

Comment: Have you tried using a Python library called weasyprint to create and render PDF's?

Comment: @dotslash227 I considered it, but was put off by the number of dependencies (CPython!). Do you think I should resort to it nevertheless?

Comment: what do you see in your browser source as the href attribute for that button? You're expecting the entire table to be inside a URL?

Comment: The view rendering your HTML with the button to download and the view returning the PDF are two separate views, therefore they process two entirely separate HTTP requests. You can't "pass a variable" from one to the other without storing something permanently. So: Store your table somewhere (either in database or on file), keep a reference to it (either in the user's session or in the database) and pass that reference to your URL and second view as query parameter.

Comment: @dirkgroten the browser source is `<a class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg" href="/whitelist/result.pdf">Download PDF</a>`. I expect the entire table to be in the PDF accessible upon clicking the button.

Comment: If you are using Linux or a Mac, Weasyprint is the best solution. you should give it chance, you will stop getting migraines! :P

Comment: @dotslash227 but the issue has nothing to do with the library used to generate the PDF. The problem is with thinking that the second view has access to the `table` variable.

Comment: OK I removed the "Table" variable from the view function and the url reference altogether, and I'm left with the **Exception Value: Request context required**. What am I missing?

Code:
`class PDFView(PDFTemplateView):
        template_name = 'whitelist/listresult.html'
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        return super(PDFView, self).get_context_data(pagesize='A4', title='Hi there!', date=date.today)`